# How to pass a record to a PL/pgSQL function?

Tags: postgresql, function, parameters, triggers, plpgsql

I have 8 similar PL/pgSQL functions; they are used as `INSTEAD OF INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` triggers on views to make them writable. The views each combine columns of one generic table (called "things" in the example below) and one special table ("shaped_things" and "flavored_things" below). PostgreSQL's inheritance feature can't be used in our case, by the way.

The triggers have to insert/update rows in the generic table; these parts are identical across all 8 functions. Since the generic table has ~30 columns, I'm trying to use a helper function there, but I'm having trouble passing the view's `NEW` record to a function that needs a `things` record as input.

(Similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716024/passing-a-record-as-function-argument-pl-pgsql) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880210/how-to-pass-a-record-as-parameter-for-pl-pgsql-function), but I don't think I can apply the suggested solutions in my case.)

#### Simplified schema

```
CREATE TABLE things (
    id    SERIAL  PRIMARY KEY,
    name  TEXT    NOT NULL
    -- (plus 30 more columns)
);
CREATE TABLE flavored_things (
    thing_id  INT   PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES things (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    flavor    TEXT  NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE shaped_things (
    thing_id  INT   PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES things (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    shape     TEXT  NOT NULL
);
-- etc...
```

#### Writable view implementation for flavored_things

```
CREATE VIEW flavored_view AS
    SELECT t.*,
           f.*
      FROM things t
      JOIN flavored_things f ON f.thing_id = t.id;

CREATE FUNCTION flavored_trig () RETURNS TRIGGER AS $fun$
DECLARE
    inserted_id  INT;
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        INSERT INTO things VALUES (  -- (A)
            DEFAULT,
            NEW.name
            -- (plus 30 more columns)
        ) RETURNING id INTO inserted_id;
        INSERT INTO flavored_things VALUES (
            inserted_id,
            NEW.flavor
        );
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
        UPDATE things SET  -- (B)
            name = NEW.name
            -- (plus 30 more columns)
        WHERE id = OLD.id;
        UPDATE flavored_things SET
            flavor = NEW.flavor
        WHERE thing_id = OLD.id;
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSIF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
        DELETE FROM flavored_things WHERE thing_id = OLD.id;
        DELETE FROM things WHERE id = OLD.id;
        RETURN OLD;
    END IF;
END;
$fun$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER write_flavored
    INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON flavored_view
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE flavored_trig();
```

The statements marked "(A)" and "(B)" above are what I would like to replace with a call to a helper function.

#### Helper function for INSERT

My initial attempt was to replace statement "(A)" with

```
inserted_id = insert_thing(NEW);
```

using this function

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_thing (new_thing RECORD) RETURNS INTEGER AS $fun$
DECLARE
    inserted_id  INT;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO things (name) VALUES (
        new_thing.name
        -- (plus 30 more columns)
    ) RETURNING id INTO inserted_id;
    RETURN inserted_id;
END;
$fun$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This fails with the error message *"PL/pgSQL functions cannot accept type record"*.

Giving the parameter the type `things` doesn't work when the function is called as `insert_thing(NEW)`: *"function insert_thing(flavored_view) does not exist"*.

Simple casting doesn't seem to be available here; `insert_thing(NEW::things)` produces *"cannot cast type flavored_view to things"*. Writing a CAST function for each view would remove what we gained by using a helper function.

Any ideas?

Comment: First off, there are various elegant solutions. Do you want to insert / update *all* columns of `thing` or just selected columns? What is your version of Postgres? What is your objective? To just make it work? To use a single function? To optimize performance? Do you have to deal with possible unique violations / race conditions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are various options, depending on the complete picture.
Basically, your insert function could work like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_thing (_thing flavored_view)
   RETURNS int AS
$func$
   INSERT INTO things (name) VALUES ($1.name) -- plus 30 more columns
   RETURNING id;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Using the row type of the **view**, because `NEW` in your trigger is of this type.
Use a simple SQL function, which can be inlined and might perform better.

Demo call:

```
SELECT insert_thing('(1, foo, 1, bar)');
```

Inside your trigger `flavored_trig ()`:

```
inserted_id := insert_thing(NEW);
```

Or, basically rewritten:

```
IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
   INSERT INTO flavored_things(thing_id, flavor)
   VALUES (insert_thing(NEW), NEW.flavor);
   RETURN NEW;
ELSIF ...
```

<strike>`record`</strike> is not a valid type outside PL/pgSQL, it's just a generic placeholder for a yet unknown row type in PL/pgSQL) so you cannot use it for an input parameter in a function declaration.

For a more dynamic function accepting **various row types** you could use a [**polymorphic type**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC). Examples:

- [How to return a table by rowtype in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649910/how-to-return-a-table-by-rowtype-in-pl-pgsql/27652936#27652936)
- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)
- [How to write a function that returns text or integer values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587735/how-to-write-a-function-that-returns-text-or-integer-values/17605114#17605114)

Comment: I could use the view's row type, but then I'd have to write one helper function for each view, which kind of defeats the purpose. `ANYELEMENT`, however, does exactly what I need. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can convert a record to a hstore variable and pass the hstore variable instead of a record variable to a function. You convert record to hstore i.e. so:

```
DECLARE r record; h hstore;
h = hstore(r);
```

Your helper function should also be changed so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_thing (new_thing hstore) RETURNS INTEGER AS $fun$
DECLARE
    inserted_id  INT;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO things (name) VALUES (
        new_thing -> 'name'
        -- (plus 30 more columns)
    ) RETURNING id INTO inserted_id;
    RETURN inserted_id;
END;
$fun$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And the call:

```
inserted_id = insert_thing(hstore(NEW));
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. The drawback with hstore is that it only handles strings well. For example, it will convert all NULL values to empty strings.

Comment: This would be more expensive and error prone due to casting to `text` and back. However, @Zilk: [hstore ***can*** deal with NULL values properly](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/hstore.html#AEN155238): `A value (but not a key) can be an SQL NULL`: `key => NULL`

Comment: You're right, it can. No idea what went wrong when I tested this earlier... my bad.

Comment: I am basically working on greenplum and hstore type doesn't exist there

Comment: May be use json as function argument and pass record as `row_to_json(record)`

Answer (score -1):

Composite types. PostgresSQL has documentation on this, you essentially need to use something like

'()' or ROW() to construct the composite type for a row to pass into a function.

Comment: can you share the patch of that documentation?  or some working example?