# Insert IF NOT EXIST, select IF EXIST

Tags: postgresql, function

Faced some misunderstanding on how does Postgresql functions works. The task is to check if some `id` already exists in my DB. If it does - return some data from existing recording. If doesn't - insert some data and return everything back.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(_id varchar, _data varchar[]) RETURNS varchar[] AS $$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_table WHERE id = _id) THEN
        SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = _id;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO my_table (id, filename, size) VALUES (_data) RETURNING *;
    END IF;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Select returns an error: `ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "id123"`

```
SELECT test('id123', ARRAY['id123', 'filename', 123456]);
```

Would be appreciated for any help.

Comment: Well, obviously `id123` is not a valid integer value - what exactly is your question?

Comment: Also, your function as written will not return varchar[], so that will also throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Passing multiple arguments for various table columns as array elements is not a good idea. You may  better use a [Composite Type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html)  as argument. This helps you to even pass multiple rows of data to functions as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28114142/7998591) example

If you insist on using array elements, you can't simply use them within `VALUES()`, they have to be referenced using the index

```
INSERT INTO my_table  (id, filename, size) 
                      VALUES (_data[1],_data[2],_data[3]::int );
```

Another problem is with `RETURNING *;` It does not return from a function. It just returns the result of the query. If you purely want to use `RETURNING` a with clause could be used.

Assuming that the the definition of your table is something like this,

```
                    Table "public.my_table"
  Column  |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default
----------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id       | character varying |           |          |
 filename | text              |           |          |
 size     | integer           |           |          |
```

you may write your function's return type as a `TABLE`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(_id varchar, _data varchar[]) 
 RETURNS TABLE (id varchar, filename text, size int)
AS $$
BEGIN
 IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM my_table t WHERE t.id = _id) THEN
   RETURN QUERY
   with  ins AS 
    ( 
      INSERT INTO my_table  (id, filename, size) 
                      VALUES (_data[1],_data[2],_data[3]::int ) RETURNING *
     )                    ---refer elements             ^ properly cast them
    SELECT * FROM ins;   
    ELSE
     RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM my_table t WHERE t.id = _id; 

    END IF;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```